# nestjs, swagger DTO extend

Tags: nestjs, swagger, typeorm

one of my response type

```
export class VoucherDto {
  @ApiProperty({ example: 'fff', required: true, description: '' })
  name!: string;

  @ApiProperty({ example: 'fff', required: false, description: '' })
  expirationPeriodStart!: Date;

  @ApiProperty({ example: 'fff', required: false, description: '' })
  expirationPeriodEnd!: Date;
}
```

my common Dto looks like this.

```
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class BaseResDto {
  @ApiProperty({ default: 1, example: 1 })
  page: number;

  @ApiProperty({ default: 1, example: 10 })
  totalPage: number;
}

export class ApiResponseWrapper<Some> extends BaseResDto {
  @ApiProperty({ type: [Object] })
  data: { Some };
}
```

but it shows like this.

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "totalPage": 10,
  "data": [
    {}
  ]
}
```

how can I show like this ?

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "totalPage": 10,
  "data": [
    {
     "name": "test",
     "expirationPeriodStart": "2024-02-01T01:41:53.770Z",
     "expirationPeriodEnd": "2024-12-01T01:41:53.770Z",
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm new to Java, nestjs, typeorm.
I followed chatGPT's solution but couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution.

```
export class ApiResponseWrapper<T> extends BaseResDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    oneOf: [
      { $ref: getSchemaPath(VoucherDto) },
      { $ref: getSchemaPath(SomeOtherDtos) },
      ...
    ],
  })
  data: T[];
}
```

and call with

ApiResponseWrapper<VoucherDto>

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**